# Need some ideas with restoring a table's content in any given point in time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table structure similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_Subscription
(
Customer_ID           INT
, Product_ID          INT
, Subscription_START  DATETIME
, Subscription_END    DATETIME
, PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID, Product_ID)
)
```

And then, I also have an audit table, like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_Subscription_Audit
(
Audit_Code             CHAR(1)
, AuditCreatedDateTime DATETIME
, Customer_ID          INT
, Product_ID           INT
, Subscription_START   DATETIME
, Subscription_END     DATETIME
)
```

Whenever a change being made to the table Customer_Subscription, I have a trigger that also writes a row to the Audit table, recording the previous values that were being changed (the unmodified version), with INSERT UPDATE DELETE being represented by Audit_Code ‘I’, ‘U’, ‘D’

I have a problem, where I want to be able to recreate the content in my Customer_Subscription table back in any given point in time in the past, using my Customer_Subscription_Audit table, and I am wondering what is the best way to go about?

(Just to make it work, I am currently thinking just loop through the audit table row by row… I know RBAR sucks.. but it should gets the job done.. But I want to see if there is a more efficient way as well)

Comment: I think you should change your logic. Firstly, in an insert there is no "previous" value. So therefore the insert row contains the current state. This is very different from the rows recorded for updates. Your logic competes with itself. If your insert row contains the current values, then the same should be done for your other actions. Why? Because for any modification, the prior row contains the before image of **the current** change. IOW, just record the current values for any action.

Comment: For deletes, the values of a given row are not actually changing. You are just recording the fact that a row was deleted and all you really need are the PK values and the delete flag. As noted already, think carefully about how you intend to interpret this information as of a given date and time. You should generate some carefully planned test data and use cases to really understand what logic you should use.

Answer (score 0):

The audit table backups the state of each row before it is modified. You could implement the logic with window functions:

```
select customer_id, product_id, subscription_start, subscription_end
from (
    select csa.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by customer_id, product_id
            order by auditcreateddatetime
        ) rn
    from customer_subscription_audit csa
    where auditcreateddatetime >= @targetdatetime
) csa
where rn = 1 and audit_code <> 'I'
```

Basically the logic is to filter on audit rows that are newer than the recovery point, and select the earliest record per customer/product tuple. Insertion events should be ignored.

Comment: Question for both. If row for (cust id 1, prod id 1) was deleted on nov 1 2020 and your target date is nov 2 2020, what should your resultset contain for (1, 1)?

Comment: @SMor: in my opinion, it should not appear in the resultset - and that's what the query does. The next event is an insertion, which we filter out.

Comment: Thank you @GMB ! I am going to try this out now, just another trivia, the audit table didnt get implemented until around 2015, so it is possible that, some records in Customer_Subscription table, that were not touched between 2015 to now, will not have any audit records, in that case, I am thinking just grab the values from my current table, if there is not a match from the audit table, do you think it will work?